# How can I model ultra-viscous, dripping wet objects?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, fluid-simulation

I saw this on [Reynante Martinez's](http://www.reynantemartinez.com/cycles-material-studies.html) site:

[image]

I want to know how those fat drips were made. My first idea would be a fluid simulation with extremely high viscosity, but I couldn't get the same sort of heavy, rich-looking drips.

My other ideas would be to model it with a half-sphere for the top, maybe do some sculpting or something to make the rips manually, then apply some sort of displacement texture to get the slight distortion on the chocolate.

Comment: It's probably sculpted, simulating this would be a waste of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sculpt the drips well, then in materials, set glossy along with Fresnel effect. You also want to use a nice HDR environment texture.
The key to obtaining such an effect is mainly Fresnel.

Comment: I don't see alot of fresnel in the image posted by the original question. Tho fresnel may improve the image :). I suspect this can be achieve without much modeling and just by applying a depth map may suffice.

Comment: @hawkenfox Depth map might suffice, but sculpting is waay easier.